# Search on GeoJson files

Tags: node.js, cordova, geojson

I developing a app based on Cordova with a geojson file and i need know if have a way to check if my current geolocation (latitude and logitude) is inside a geojson:linestring. This app work offline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution using jq (https://stedolan.github.io/jq).

Given a valid geojson object, report(latLong) as defined here will return *true* each time an object with "type" equal to "LineString" and "coordinates" having the specified latLong is encountered as the geojson object is traversed.

```
def report(latLong):
  if type == "object"
     and .type == "LineString"
     and (.coordinates | type) == "array"
     and (.coordinates | index([latLong])) then true
  elif type == "array" or type == "object" then .[] | report(latLong)
  else empty
  end;
```

One way to use this definition is to put it into a file, say geojson.jq,
together with the following line:

```
report($latLong | fromjson)
```

Here is an example that assumes the geojson object at  http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#examples is in a file called geojson.json:

```
$ jq --arg latLong "[103.0, 1.0]" -f geojson.jq geojson.json

true
```

There are other ways to use the above-defined report/1, and of course there are variants of report/1 that could be defined, e.g. to yield something other than *true*.